# Does god really accept our prayers despite our wandering mind, our desires, pleasure seeking intentions and praying just for the wish to be fulfilled?

Tags: gods, moksha, worship, life, prayer

I actually am perplexed by consuming information from various sources and would like to put it out in words now. I fall in an endless mind chatter when thinking about my prayers and god  fulfilling our wishes. We all are expressions in physical form and believe in fulfilling our wishes by addressing them in our prayers to god.
Why do we be asking  for success, possessions or material pleasures while we are always meant to leave these bodies?
I don't know about everyone but the society I lived in gave me this real bad Idea to be better than someone while I think we all have been blessed uniquely. Why do someone think like that, we didn't create anything, we don't take anything, we only use the resources in our time.

Comment: Pray but do not rely on pray, karma is also compulsory.

Answer (score 1):

```
   TOKEN OF ACCEPTANCE: SATH
```

"Does god really accept our prayers?"

YES, REALLY. Prayers are not for name sske snd they must be performed according to Aagama.

```
  Human of DESIRE : VIMOHITAN
```

An individual may be desirous at a time. But, it is not required all individuals are such at same time. Hence when mind of individual is free from lust/anger/greed he/she may be healthy.

While healthy, a person may be able to assist many others of callibre enabling them to worship GOD collectively. Care must be taken that persons of lust/weak thoughts must not be part of THAT DAY WORSHIP.

THEN GOD WILL FULFILL WISHES.

```
 HINDERANCE : YAGNYA ASISHTA
```

Disturbances created by Demon spirits through weak humans to disturb Worshipper may force such person towards anger/lust.

Hence first step in YAGNYA - Worship seeking gifts/wishes to be fulfilled must always be GUARDED.

Comment: That's really useful and forward in a way I never thought, Sir Srinivasan. Thanks very much